# Android Headset buttons

Tags: android

My HTC headset has 3 buttons. Next/Pause/Previous.

I can emulate the pause button in my code by calling ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON.

How can i emulate The Next and the Previous button?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use `ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON`. There is an `EXTRA_KEY_EVENT` that holds a `KeyEvent` tied to which specific media button was pressed. `KEYCODE_MEDIA_NEXT` and `KEYCODE_MEDIA_PREVIOUS` are likely candidates to map to your particular buttons, but you may have to experiment.